# Визуализация кластеризованных меток (тепловая карта)

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Использую LoadingObjectManager для отображения меток на карте и их кластеризации. Возникла потребность вывести области их концентрации в виде тепловой карты примерно как на прикреплённом изображении. Есть ли какое-то решение из коробки, куда копать если нет?

[image: Распределение меток]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: добавил упоминание тепловой карты

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данные можно загрузить не в LoadingObjectManager, а сразу в модуль heatmap, тогда на карте будет тепловая карта https://github.com/yandex/mapsapi-heatmap